# How to validate DataFrame Row on the basis of priority validation rule?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I want to validate `DataFrame` on the basis of certain rules consist in another  `DataFrame` named as Rule.
What is the best way to validate input `DataFrame` on the basis of Rule `DataFrame`, if any row applicable for multiple rules check then get only highest priority validation and give data as below:

**Input DataFrame:**

```
+---+----+----+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Id|Name|City|Country|Pincode|flatA|flagB|flagC|flagD|
+---+----+----+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1|   A| MUM|  INDIA| 100010| null|    Y|    Y| null|
|  2|   B| MUM|  INDIA| 200020| null| null|    Y| null|
|  3|   C| MUM|  INDIA| 100030| null| null| null|    Y|
|  4|   D| MUM|  INDIA| 500050|    Y|    Y| null| null|
|  5|   E| MUM|  INDIA|3078787| null| null|    Y|    Y|
+---+----+----+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

**Rule Dataframe:**

```
+------+----+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+
|Rules#|City|Country|flatA|flagB|flagC|flagD|Pincode|Priority|
+------+----+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+
|     1| MUM|  INDIA| null|    Y| null| null| 100010|       3|
|     2| MUM|  INDIA| null| null|    Y| null| 200020|       4|
|     3| MUM|  INDIA| null| null| null|    Y| 300030|       6|
|     4| MUM|  INDIA| null|    Y|    Y| null| 400040|       2|
|     5| MUM|  INDIA|    Y|    Y| null| null| 500050|       1|
|     6| MUM|  INDIA| null| null|    Y|    Y| 600060|       5|
+------+----+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+
```

**Expected Output:**

```
+---+----+----+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------------+-----------+
| Id|Name|City|Country|Pincode|flatA|flagB|flagC|flagD|ValidationFlag|New_PinCode|
+---+----+----+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------------+-----------+
|  1|   A| MUM|  INDIA| 100010| null|    Y|    Y| null|         FALSE|     400040|
|  2|   B| MUM|  INDIA| 200020| null| null|    Y| null|          TRUE|     200020|
|  3|   C| MUM|  INDIA| 100030| null| null| null|    Y|         FALSE|     300030|
|  4|   D| MUM|  INDIA| 500050|    Y|    Y| null| null|          TRUE|     500050|
|  5|   E| MUM|  INDIA|3078787| null| null|    Y|    Y|         FALSE|     200020|
+---+----+----+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------------+-----------+
```

As per example above, for `Id #1` in `Input Dataframe` **rules 1,2 & 4** all are applicable but it has picked **Rule#4** as per priority.

Rule check logic are as below:

> **Priority 2:** Input.City == Rule.City AND Input.Country == Rule.Country
>   AND Input.flagB == Y AND Input.flagC == Y
>
> **Priority 3:** Input.City ==
>   Rule.City AND Input.Country == Rule.Country AND  Input.flagB == Y
>
> **Priority 4:** Input.City == Rule.City AND Input.Country == Rule.Country
>   AND Input.flagC == Y
>
> Any  null Column in Rule DataFrame should be ignore in AND condition

Value of new Column `ValidationFlag` in `Output DataFrame` will be `False` if `new_PinCode` does not match with `PinCode` column otherwise it will be `True`. Another new Column `new_PinCode` contain the `PinCode` which get from `Rule Dataframe` on the basis of priority.

Comment: on which basis you are saying input-df #id 1 is matching to 1,2,4 of rule_df bcoz flat column values are different.

Comment: I have updated Rule logic, Let me know in case any more concern